# Are Python socket objects thread safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, udp

I've planning on designing a UDP server that works as follows: I will be communicating with clients that are behind a firewall and need to be able to send data at any time. Therefore, the client will first initiate a connection to me and periodically keep the connection alive by regularly sending keep alive packets. When I receive one, I need to acknowledge it. At the same time, if I have any data to send, I need to immediately send it. I've put together the following test code:

```
import threading
import queue
import socket
import time

class SharedAddress():
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.addr = ()

    def set_addr(self, addr):
        self.lock.acquire()
        self.addr = addr
        self.lock.release()

    def get_addr(self):
        self.lock.acquire()
        addr = self.addr
        self.lock.release()
        return addr

class Reader(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, socket, shared_address):
        super().__init__(name='Reader Thread')
        self.socket = socket
        self.shared_address = shared_address

    def run(self):
        while True:
            # Wait for data from the client
            data, addr = self.socket.recvfrom(4096)
            #print("Received data from {}".format(addr))
            # Echo it back
            self.socket.sendto(data, addr)
            self.shared_address.set_addr(addr)

class Writer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, socket, shared_address):
        super().__init__(name='Writer Thread')
        self.socket = socket
        self.tx_queue = queue.Queue()
        self.shared_address = shared_address

    def run(self):
        while True:
            # Wait for data to be received
            data = self.tx_queue.get()
            # Send it to the client
            addr = self.shared_address.get_addr()
            if addr:
                self.socket.sendto(data, addr)



### Main loop
# Create the socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('', 2000))

sa = SharedAddress()

r = Reader(s, sa)
w = Writer(s, sa)

r.start()
w.start()

while True:
    w.tx_queue.put(b'>>Hi this is a message<<\n')
    time.sleep(0.1)

r.join()
w.join()

print("Program ended")
```

Although the code appears to work, I'm concerned about the fact that I'm using the same socket object from two different threads without any sort of lock. I then modified the Writer class to create its own socket object:

```
class Writer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, shared_address):
        super().__init__(name='Writer Thread')
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) 
        self.tx_queue = queue.Queue()
        self.shared_address = shared_address
```

This also seems to work just fine. My questions are as follows:

- Are socket objects thread safe?
- If you create multiple UDP socket objects in Python and use them to send data to same address, do they actually end up referencing the same underlying connection object?
- What happens if I call the close command on one of the socket objects? Presumably it will close the underlying OS socket and prevent the other socket objects from then receiving and transmitting.